# Facebook request Dialog filter app_non_users not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-requests

I'm using facebook apprequest dialog, and  filter friends who already using the app.

```
 FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  appid:'1234567890',
  filters: '['app_non_users']',
 }, requestCallback);
```

Anybody facing same issue? Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please specify what behavior you are actually seeing. Are you getting a segmentation fault with core dumped? Is Facebook returning the names of all the movies in its database?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works, but it depends on person's privacy settings.

If user has 'Visibility of app' option set to 'only me' value, he/she is listed as 'non app user' even if he/she uses the app.

Simply said, if your friend does not share any info about app with you, you cannot get any info about this.

Seems reasonable to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write:

```
filters: ['app_non_users']
```